# How to date format an SQL result using Diesel?

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I am using Diesel to query a DB in PostgreSQL using JOINs:

```
let product_id = 1;
sales::table
     .inner_join(product::table)
     .select((
         product::description,
         sales::amount,
         sales::date_sale
     ))
     .filter(sales::product_id.eq(product_id))
     .load(&diesel::PgConnection)
```

My model:

```
pub struct Sales {
    pub id: i32,
    pub product_id: Option<i32>,
    pub amount: Option<BigDecimal>,
    pub date_sale: Option<NaiveDateTime>
}
```

The result is as expected, but I need to give a date format to the field `sales::date_sale` that in pgadmin I do it with `to_char(date_sale, 'dd/mm/YYYY')`.

Is it possible to use `to_char` in Diesel or in what way can I modify the data that the Diesel ORM brings me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the answers provided by `harmic` there are two more possibilities to solve this problem.

## [`sql_function!`](https://docs.rs/diesel/1.4.4/diesel/macro.sql_function.html)

Diesel provides an interface to easily define query ast nodes for sql functions that are not provided by diesel itself. Users are encouraged to use this functionality to define missing functions on their own. (In fact diesel uses internally the same method to define query ast nodes for sql functions provided out of the box). The defined query ast node is usable in every context where the types of its expression are valid, so it can be used in select and where clauses.
(This is basically the type safe version of the raw sql solution above)

For the given question something like this should work:

```rust
#[derive(Queryable)]
pub struct Sales {
    pub id: i32,
    pub product_id: Option<i32>,
    pub amount: Option<BigDecimal>,
    pub date_sale: Option<String>,
}

sql_function! {
    fn to_char(Nullable<Timestamp>, Text) -> Nullable<Text>;
}

let product_id = 1;
sales::table
     .inner_join(product::table)
     .select((
         product::description,
         sales::amount,
         to_char(sales::date_sale, "dd/mm/YYYY")
     ))
     .filter(sales::product_id.eq(product_id))
     .load(&diesel::PgConnection);
```

## [`#[derive(Queryable)]` + `#[diesel(deserialize_as = "Type")]`](https://docs.rs/diesel/1.4.4/diesel/deserialize/trait.Queryable.html#deriving)

Diesels `Queryable` derive provides a way to apply certain type manipulations at load time via a custom attribute. In combination with the `chrono` solution provided by `harmic` this gives the following variant:

```rust
#[derive(Queryable)]
pub struct Sales {
    pub id: i32,
    pub product_id: Option<i32>,
    pub amount: Option<BigDecimal>,
    #[diesel(deserialize_as = "MyChronoTypeLoader")]
    pub date_sale: Option<String>
}

struct MyChronoTypeLoader(Option<String>);

impl Into<Option<String>> for MyChronoTypeLoader {
    fn into(self) -> String {
        self.0
    }
}

impl<DB, ST> Queryable<ST, DB> for MyChronoTypeLoader
where
    DB: Backend,
    Option<NaiveDateTime>: Queryable<ST, DB>,
{
    type Row = <Option<NaiveDateTime> as Queryable<ST, DB>>::Row;

    fn build(row: Self::Row) -> Self {
        MyChronoTypeLoader(Option::<NaiveDateTime>::build(row).map(|d| d.format("%d/%m/%Y").to_string()))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using an ORM, data is extracted from the database in the most suitable representation for interpretation by the ORM; after which you would manipulate it in the target domain (rust in this case).

Since `date_sale` is an `Option<NaiveDateTime>`, you can use the formatting options provided by [chrono](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.3.1/chrono/index.html):

```
sale.date_sale.unwrap().format("%d/%m/%Y").to_string()
```

(Your real code would not use `unwrap()`, of course!)

Alternatively, if you really need the database to do the formatting, you could use a `[sql][2]` to insert some raw SQL into your query:

```
let results = sales::table.select((sales::id, sql("to_char(date_sale, 'dd/mm/YYYY')")))
    .load::<(i32, String)>(&conn);
```

This would be more useful if you were trying to implement some logic that would be more easy or efficient to implement in SQL.

An example would be a filtering condition: suppose you wanted to include rows from your table where the week number was an even number. While you could load the whole table and then filter it in the rust domain, that would not be very efficient. Instead you could do this:

```
let results = sales::table
    .filter(sql("extract(week from date_sale)::smallint % 2=0"))
    .load::<Sales>(&conn);
```